# Windows 8 missing from GRUB menu

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, boot-repair

I have windows 8 preinstalled on my laptop. Initially I installed Ubuntu 12 LTS but I coudnt boot it with UEFI enabled, on using boot-repair it told me that this version of ubuntu is not supported by EFI.
So i installed ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64 and during the setup choose the option remove Ubuntu 12 LTS and install ubuntu 13.
After the installation ubuntu starts but there is no windows entry in grub, so I ran boot repair from the live cd again but still it did not show windows 8. This is the url it generated:
[paste.ubuntu.com/7076240](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7076240)

Then I ran boot-repair from ubuntu and it finished with this url:
[paste.ubuntu.com/7076405](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7076405)

Now there is one more entry in Grub but none of them open Windows 8. Also I am unable to mount the windows partiton to reach my files.

I tried the method said in one of the forums where you update the grub manually to point to windows efi file but I coudnt find the (hdo,gptx) x number recquired to do it.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You've wiped out your Windows installation. You'll need to contact Microsoft or your laptop's manufacturer to get a DVD set or USB flash drive with a set of recovery images. I recommend trying Microsoft, because the set provided by the manufacturer will probably wipe out your Ubuntu installation. (Even to install a version provided by Microsoft, you'll need to resize your Linux partition before you begin.)